# How did the term "X's finest" come to mean the police force of a city X?

Tags: etymology

I have often come across terms like *London's finest*, *New York's finest*, etc., intended to mean the police forces of the respective cities. I think in the case of Scotland Yard, the term even has some official currency. How did this usage originate? Was it sarcastic or propaganda?

It's hard to believe that the finest people of a city are its policemen, especially given how often popular tales involve thieves and outlaws as protagonists.

Comment: I've never heard of the Metropolitan Police (or the City of London Police) referred to as "London's finest". I live in the UK and, since so much of the country's news relates to London and the police are very often mentioned in the news, I'm sure I would have heard it in hundreds of news reports if it was at all common.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Selection bias at work, I suppose. For some reason, I have always associated that phrase with London. Perhaps because I have seen that phrase in some work of fiction, and considered that usage for the Metropolitan Police to be preeminent.

Comment: Yeah, it was probably somebody saying "London's finest" by analogy with "New York's finest". It's not a phrase that's in common use.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, the oldest reference to "London's Finest" I can dig up is [this 1909 work](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=YjY_AQAAMAAJ&q=%22london%27s+finest%22+~police&dq=%22london%27s+finest%22+~police&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hKmWVL3ELZHluQT32IHICQ&ved=0CBoQ6AEwADhG#v=snippet&q=%22london's%20finest%22%20~police&f=false), which makes we wonder where I read that phrase. I haven't read many modern works centred on London.

Comment: @muru: That 1909 mentions "London's finest" right after talking about New York.

Comment: @Hugo indeed it does.

Comment: Alert Society's Finest, the Thought Police - people are using the term "X's Finest" in a manner that is inconsistent with the literal meanings of the words!

Comment: My guess would be that "New York's Finest" was a cliche promoted by New York's Finest at some time in the past and it stuck.  On rare occasions one hears "LA's Finest" or "Chicago's Finest", but it's more likely to be used sarcastically than as a complementary term.  (And "New York's Finest" is quite often used sarcastically as well.)

Comment: I've never heard it used in respect of any UK police force at all. The only time I've ever heard it is when in America.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In the case of "New York's Finest," Barry [Popik] has traced the term back to
>   the 1870s, where it apparently first emerged in the form "the finest
>   police force in the world," a phrase associated with George Matsell
>   (police chief at the time), and possibly modeled on Civil War Major
>   General Joseph Hooker's estimation of his troops as "the finest army
>   on the planet." The general idea of New York's police being "the finest" had been asserted in print for several years by that point, so it
>   wasn't surprising that eventually the tribute was codified in the
>   phrase "New York's Finest."

http://www.word-detective.com/0806C.html

I've never heard the police in London referred to as "London's finest", and a search for that phrase results in must-see landmarks, expensive hotels, hairdressers, dance troupes and man-and-van services. But adding the word police shows the Metropolitan Police do (or have) used the phrase:

> A career with London's finest

http://content.met.police.uk/News/A-career-with-Londons-finest/1260267625884/1257246745756

I don't think it's an official term in London, unlike New York and some other American cities.

Comment: That is confusing. How does 'X's finest' imply that X's finest is *the finest of something in the whole world*? After all, there is only one police force in a given city.

Comment: Well, obviously NYPD are the best PD in NY because they're the only one. But you can still compare PDs from different cities in terms of policing abilities. But we shouldn't confuse original meanings with current meanings. What was first meant by X's finest is different to now. Word meanings change all the time. Now people generally mean they're the finest in that city. See also "The bravest" for the FDNY.

Comment: I suppose there's the confusion. I always assumed it to mean the finest of the people in a city, rather than the finest of the police force(s) in a city.

Comment: @muri, Yes, the implication is *only the finest men in the city are admitted to the police force*, and of course *the finest men of the city aspire to become members of the olive force*. In other words, if you're looking for the *finest people in the city, look in the police force*.

Comment: @DanBron that was my understanding, but it seems so outrageously false.

Comment: _After all, there is only one police force in a given city_

@muru this is not necessarily true – London for instance has two: Metropolitan Police and City of London Police. Their jurisdiction is clear, with the met operating outside of City bounds and City police conversely only operating within City bounds. I'd be surprised if London is the only place in the world with more than one police force.

Comment: @macke Did that split always exist? And are there cases where police forces share jurisdictions within a city?

Comment: If Theodore Roosevelt's very readable [account of his stint as the President of the Police Commission of New York](http://www.bartleby.com/55/6.html) is to be believed, by 1895 there were plenty of reasons to be highly sceptical about the accuracy of the "New York's Finest" epithet.

Comment: Given "Fighting Joe" Hooker's humiliating defeat with that "finest army" and subsequent sacking I would doubt any link with that statement unless it was meant ironically from the start.  That has gone down in history as the epitome in overconfident blatherings by a General.

Comment: @muru as far as I know. The overly simplified history is that some thousand odd years ago, William the conqueror was unable to take the place by force, so kind of gave up and took everything around it. Eventually a deal was struck, giving the City a special charter, and the idea of a special status granted to the City remains to this day, however in different forms obviously – specifically policing has always been one area where the City has its own jurisdiction. They don't share jurisdiction with the Met I don't think, but probably cooperate in some ways.

Answer (score 5):

In NYC, the police are "NY's Finest", the firemen are "NY's Bravest" and the sanitation workers are "NY's Strongest".  ("Everybody wants to get into the act" - Jimmy Durante)

Comment: Hugo's link also mentions these terms. *Everybody wants to get into the act* is a TV show, I presume?

Comment: @muru - no, it's a quotation attributed to Durante.

Comment: @muru - I'm sure "Everybody wants to get into the act" predates TV -- probably refers to vaudeville.

Comment: @HotLicks possibly, but I didn't get how Oldbag is linking the quote with with the first sentence. Googling showed some mentions of a TV show.

Comment: Oldbag -- So what is the superlative for NY politicians?

Comment: It's an *old* cliche.  Say you have a committee of 10 people.  You have a chair and vice chair and secretary and treasurer, then the other 6 people feel left out and want jobs as well.

Comment: @HotLicks- Thanx for covering for me, I was @ work. As for the politicians, there are expletives, but no superlatives.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Eighth Amendment.

> Excessive bail shall not be required, nor **excessive fines** imposed, nor cruel and unusual punishments inflicted.

People are simply making neutral comments about the **superlative traffic fines** they are paying.

Comment: This seems somewhat unlikely as a source for the term.

Answer (score -1):

During the Civil War rioters in New York protested the unfairness of the draft. (It's a rich man's war but a poor man's fight.) It was wild enough that Lincoln ordered soldiers from the Army Of the Potomac to go to New York to restore order. Before the soldiers got to New York the police had won the street battles and ended the riot. The New York P.D. had earned the title New York's Finest in combat. **Other police departments have not earned the title.**

Comment: Needs references.